# Adding multiple values to each column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, aix

I'm really new at using awk/sed

So, I have text file that is called performance.log that has following info

```
CPU 1 2 3 4 5 6
RAM 2 3 4 5 6 7
HAR 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

And with in the code in performance-eval.sh, function generates following info

```
Cur_CPU=10
Cur_RAM=11
Cur_HAR=13
```

I want to insert and save Cur_CPU,RAM,HAR to performance.log.
Cur_CPU will go to first row, second column
Cur_RAM will go to second row, second column
Cur_HAR will go to third row, second column

So that resulting performance.log would be

```
CPU 10 1 2 3 4 5 6
RAM 11 2 3 4 5 6 7
HAR 13 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I'm not sure how to add 3 different values into 3 different columns. 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use the `join` command, but first you need to process the output of function that generates the additional info:

```
function | sed -e 's/^Cur_//;s/=/ /' | sort > myfile2.txt
join myfile2.txt myfile1.txt -1 1 -2 1
```

We start by removing the `Cur_` from the start of each line, then we replace `=` with a space character. Also, join expects both inputs to be properly sorted.

The `-1 1` argument tells join that for the first file, it should use the first field as a join field. Analogously, `-2 1` tells join that for the second file, it should use the first field too (in some implementations you could shorten into a single `-N 1`, so it uses the first field for both files).

The join field is used as so: when join finds a line in the first file with the same join field as the line on the second file, the output contains the merged lines. Notice that the order of the files in the command line is important to the order of the fields in the final output.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: So am i suppose to put performance-eval.sh | sed -e 's/^Cur_//;s/=/ /' | sort > myfile2.txt
join myfile2.txt myfile1.txt -1 1 -2 1     in performance-eval.sh? I'm trying to do cronjob for performance-eval.sh so i cant' just execute this file every time

Comment: Sorry. I think I missunderstood your post. What you have to do is process the output of the function that generates the info (the lines that are like `Cur_CPU=10`). I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is way with `awk`:

```
$ cat output 
Cur_CPU=10
Cur_RAM=11
Cur_HAR=13
```

```
$ cat perf.log 
CPU 1 2 3 4 5 6
RAM 2 3 4 5 6 7
HAR 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{split($0, fld, /=|_/);a[fld[2]] = fld[2] FS fld[3];next}
($1 in a){$1 = a[$1]}1' output perf.log 
CPU 10 1 2 3 4 5 6
RAM 11 2 3 4 5 6 7
HAR 13 3 4 5 6 7 8
```